# Use JBuilder to create JSON variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

Can I use JBuilder to create a JSON and store it in a variable?

I ask this because building JSON's are really easy using JBuilder but I need to use this JSON instead of rendering it as the response which is what JBuilder usually does

Comment: seek inspiration here: https://github.com/gazay/gon

Comment: You can use [`to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) method. `jBuilder` should be used for create views in json.

Comment: @Зелёный you can use jbuilder to create json for whatever purpose

Comment: @apneadiving thanks, i dont know this.